# How to prevent Duplicate Signals in Django

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have added a notification where every time a user submits a Like button to a post, the owner of the liked post receives a notification.

I have set Value options for each Like button to be Like or Unlike I have restricted the notification to be sent only if the Value of the like clicked is Like only.

So, now in the Like Model I have added signal and a condition that if the Like.value== Like the signal activates but for some reason it is sent twice only when a new post is created and a new user clicks like for the very first time, afterwards if he unike and likes again it is sent once.

**My question is:**

Why is the signal duplicated everytime a new user clicks the Like button?
How to fix it?

*Here is the post models.py:*

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked', blank=True)
```

*here is the Like model.py*:

```
LIKE_CHOICES = (
    ('Like', 'Like'),
    ('Unlike', 'Unlike')
)


class Like(models.Model):
    # To know Who liked
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, default='Like', max_length=8)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.post}-{self.user}-{self.value}"

    def user_liked_post(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        like = instance
        if like.value=='Like':
            post = like.post
            sender = like.user
            notify = Notification(post=post, sender=sender, user=post.author, notification_type=1)
            notify.save()


    def user_unlike_post(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        like = instance
        post = like.post
        sender = like.user
        notify = Notification.objects.filter(post=post, sender=sender, user=post.author, notification_type=1)
        notify.delete()


# Likes
post_save.connect(Like.user_liked_post, sender=Like)
post_delete.connect(Like.user_unlike_post, sender=Like)
```

*Here is the views.py:*

```
def ShowNotifications(request):
    user=request.user
    notifications= Notification.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-date')
    template= loader.get_template('notifications/notifications.html')

    context= {
        'notifications':notifications
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_author')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.post.title}@_{self.user}"

@receiver(post_save, sender=Like)
def user_liked_post(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        if created:
            notify = Notification(
                post=instance.post,
                sender=instance.user,
                user=instance.post.author,
                notification_type=1
            )
            notify.save()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error sending liked notification!')
        print(e)

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Like)
def user_unlike_post(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        notify = Notification.objects.filter(
            post=instance.post,
            sender=instance.user,
        )
        notify.delete()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error deleting liked notification!')
        print(e)
```

Since you are deleting the liked record then the status of the record will never be `unlike` and the `updated` field is also not going to update.
So remove the update and value fields from `Like` model.

And in below line you are fetching the `author` from `Post` model but there is no author field in `Post` model.

```
notify = Notification(post=post, sender=sender, user=post.author, notification_type=1)
```

Comment: I am receiving `NameError: name 'Like' is not defined` and the error coming from `@receiver(post_save, sender=Like)`

Comment: That is because of the indentation in the signals. I have edited the answer try again.

Comment: It worked,  could you add to your answer an explanation of what is the difference between the 2 methods. I am trying to understand what happened